# Unable to drag and drop element using Selenium Web driver ( Python )

Tags: python, selenium, drag-and-drop, webdriver, drag

On trying to perform drag and drop using selenium webdriver, the following traceback is thrown .

```
File
"/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.15.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py",
line 44, in perform
    action()   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.15.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py",
line 201, in <lambda>
    self._driver.execute(Command.MOVE_TO, {'element': to_element.id})) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'`
```

Code Snippet :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
ac = ActionChains()
source = driver.get_element_by_xpath(<xpath>)
target = driver.get_element_by_xpath(<xpath>)
ac.drag_and_drop(source, target).perfrom()
```

Even click_and_hold also throwing the same error. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Have you double-checked that both of your xpaths uniquely identify web elements on the screen?

Comment: Yeah. Xpaths are uniquely identifying elements. Somehow above mentioned code is working properly now.

Comment: @sans09 did you find a solution?